# ruby loop is exiting prematurely

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
files = ["message_21.txt", "message_10.txt", "message_27.txt", "message_22.txt", "message_23.txt", "message_15.txt", "message_4.txt", "message_16.txt", "message_24.txt", "message_13.txt", "message_1.txt", "message_3.txt", "message_17.txt", "message_12.txt", "message_2.txt", "message_19.txt", "message_18.txt", "message_14.txt", "message_25.txt", "message_9.txt", "message_8.txt", "message_5.txt", "message_26.txt", "message_11.txt", "message_7.txt", "message_20.txt", "message_6.txt", "message_28.txt"]

files.each do |f|
file = File.new(PATH + "/" + f, "r")
        while (line = file.gets)
         @found=true if line =~ /You purchased/
         next unless @found
         puts line
         exit if line =~ /Order for/
    end
    file.close
end
```

If message_4.txt contain 'You purchased' and 'order' term completely exit from loop. So I can't get other files which contains these terms. I don't know what mistake i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to break out of the while loop once you reach 'Order for'? Because 'exit' isn't what you are looking for. Try 'break' instead. Also you'll need to reset your @found variable for each file.

```
files = ["message_21.txt", "message_10.txt", "message_27.txt", "message_22.txt", "message_23.txt", "message_15.txt", "message_4.txt", "message_16.txt", "message_24.txt", "message_13.txt", "message_1.txt", "message_3.txt", "message_17.txt", "message_12.txt", "message_2.txt", "message_19.txt", "message_18.txt", "message_14.txt", "message_25.txt", "message_9.txt", "message_8.txt", "message_5.txt", "message_26.txt", "message_11.txt", "message_7.txt", "message_20.txt", "message_6.txt", "message_28.txt"]

files.each do |f|
  @found = false
  file = File.new(PATH + "/" + f, "r")
  while (line = file.gets)
    @found=true if line =~ /You purchased/
    # below skips to start of next run of while loop
    next unless @found 
    puts line
    # below breaks out of while loop
    break if line =~ /Order for/ 
  end
  file.close
end
```

Have a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm - especially the 'next' and 'break' explanations.

Answer (score 0):

`exit` exits the whole program, not just the loop. You need to `break`, not `exit`, to stop a loop.

You can also take advantage of `File.open` accepting a block, which will close the file for you when the block returns.

There is also no need for `@found`, unless you are intentionally storing that a `You purchased` line was found at least once in at least one file.

Finally, you should fix your indenting to use two spaces per level, as is the accepted standard in the Ruby community.

```
files = [...]

files.each do |f|
  File.open(PATH + "/" + f, "r") do |file|
    while line = file.gets
      next unless line =~ /You purchased/
      puts line
      break if line =~ /Order for/
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried 'break'. If i m using break showing all the content in the file. But I need the lines inbetween 'you purchased' and 'order'.

Comment: Does the "Order for" line also include "You purchased"? If not, the loop will never reach the `break if...` line.